# Is website's metadata stored on my pc?

Tags: browser, metadata

I'm working on a project that need to read metadata of any website visited to get website keywords from it, and I was wondering if this data is stored on my computer or not?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by meta-data? Also I understand your site wants to get information about other sites in the browse? That's very unlikely to happen with a modern, secure browser...

Comment: I am developing a desktop application that needs to get website's meta tags to apply some kind of algorithms on it. @Dan